# Celestial Mode Line throwing Error loading "celestial-mode-line" autoloads: (void-variable lunar-phases)

Tags: init-file, config, autoload

On startup am seeing this error and then the package is loading and working showing in modeline.

> Warning (emacs): Error loading "celestial-mode-line" autoloads: (void-variable lunar-phases)

emacs-lisp source block looks like this,

```
(setq calendar-longitude 25.5)
(setq calendar-latitude 17.5)
(setq calendar-location-name "Someplace")
(use-package celestial-mode-line
  :config
  ;; add to end of global-mode-string
  (if (null global-mode-string)
      (setq global-mode-string '("" celestial-mode-line-string))  ;; this means "" represents global modeline celestial-mode-line-string is right to that so celestial will show at extreme right after global modeline.
    (add-to-list 'global-mode-string 'celestial-mode-line-string t))
  (celestial-mode-line-start-timer))
```

This Package is used in addition to Melpa package = spaceline
following is config working so far sharing just in case thats the cause.

```
(use-package spaceline
:ensure t
:config
(require 'spaceline-config)
(setq powerline-default-seperator (quote arrow))
  (spaceline-spacemacs-theme) ;; Just changes the way it looks doesnt changes the colors of the theme.

(setq display-time-format "%H:%M %a,%d %b %Y") ;; default block "%H:%M:%S %a,%d %b %Y"
(display-time)   
)
```

Environments details:

- OS: Windows 10
- Emacs version: GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-07-31 (installed through chocolatey package manager)
- Package Manager inside emacs: Elpaca (without symlinks)
- Vanila emacs from scratch configuration.

I am very new to adding packages and configuration, I am doing some very basic mistake, tried contanting the author of that Plugin but sadly he/she's not active on github for some a year now.

I can share any log or init messages.

[![This is what loaded Dashboard looks.][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmaru.png

Comment: Finding 1: I went to installation directory: `~/.emacs.d/elpaca/builds/celestial-mode-line/celestial-mode-line-autoloads.el` in the end of the content, theres a line > lunar-phases am unable to figure out whats this, i commented that out and theres no error now but am not sure i have broken some component of the package or now :(.

Comment: Likely a duplicate question. Search for "void variable" here. Find out where `lunar-phases` is defined, and load the library that defines it before you invoke code that tries to use it.

Comment: I dont understand drew why u coming everywhere and picking on me instead of helping me :).

Comment: Ok inside `~\.emacs.d\elpaca\builds\celestial-mode-line` there are three files: `celestial-mode-line.el` `celestial-mode-line.elc` and `celestial-mode-line-autoloads.el`
now after commenting out autoloads directory in previous comment theres no where this phrase `lunar-phases` is used.
In M-x Describe-Variables > Searching for `lunar-phases` theres nothing exact, very close can be,
`lunar-phases-buffer` nowhere inside init or config file `lunar-phases` is mentioned.
As mentioned before theres no error now but am not sure whther I broke something or not.

Comment: Put all relevant info in the question itself, please. Comments can be deleted at any time, and they're not searchable, googlable, etc.

Comment: I guess u want to put possible solution in the question itself, i will do that sire ^^ I started the issue on official github page for the package and explained my solution there too. My best guess is the developer had some other package initialization when it triggers this package.

Comment: No, don't put the answer in the question; post it separately, as an answer. Post all *information relevant to the question* **in the question**, not in comments.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok done mr Drew, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

(atleast which worked for me) Edit `~/.emacs.d/elpaca/builds/celestial-mode-line/celestial-mode-line-autoloads.el` now at last line you see `lunar-phases` put inside double-quotes or just comment it out or just delete it. Like this `"lunar-phases"` or `;; lunar-phases`

As mentioned before theres no error now, and package working properly showing the states of moon and sun, but am not sure whether I broke something or not though. Thank you everyone may it help someone.